# Why does Solve not find solutions in terms of radicals?

Tags: equation-solving

Let's consider the following system of polynomial equations. The `s` and the capital `S` are two different variables (I know the capital-s is not recommended).

```
eqOrig = {s^2 - S^2 - b[0] - (S b[3] - s b[4])^2/(
     4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) + (-s b[3] - S b[4])^2/(
     4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) - (S b[2] + s b[5])^2/(
     4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) + (-s b[2] + S b[5])^2/(
     4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) - (S b[1] - s b[6])^2/(
     4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) + (-s b[1] - S b[6])^2/(4 (s^2 + S^2)^2) == 0, 
   2 s S + ((S b[3] - s b[4]) (-s b[3] - S b[4]))/(
     2 (s^2 + S^2)^2) + ((S b[2] + s b[5]) (-s b[2] + S b[5]))/(
     2 (s^2 + S^2)^2) + ((S b[1] - s b[6]) (-s b[1] - S b[6]))/(
     2 (s^2 + S^2)^2) - b[7] == 0};
```

After the substitution

```
eqReducedOrderGB = 
  GroebnerBasis[
    Join[eqOrig, {s*S == stS, s^2 + S^2 == s2pS2}], {stS, s2pS2}, {s, S}, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]
```

I can reduce the order of the initial equation from 8 to 4, and then solve the reduced equation in terms of radicals

```
(soleqReducedOrderGB = 
  Solve[Thread[eqReducedOrderGB == 0], {stS, s2pS2}]) // LeafCount
(* 40445 *)
```

The solution is given in terms of  radicals

```
FreeQ[soleqReducedOrderGB, _Root]
(*True*)
```

If, instead, I solve the initial equation (do not try this unless you really want to investigate the problem since it takes few hours using Mma10.3)

```
(solOrig = Solve[eqOrig, {s, S}]) // LeafCount
(*5382364097*) !!!
```

The solution given for the first variable is simple enough.

```
solSolve[[1]][[1]] // LeafCount
(*7237*)
```

However, it cannot be written in terms of radicals

```
FreeQ[ToRadicals[solSolve[[1]][[1]]], _Root]
(* False *)
```

I think that the property (of a  solution being written in radicals) should depend only on the equation itself and not on the way equation is solved.

Comment: ... and your question is? why the two solutions are expressed differently? how you can show that they are equivalent? What would you like to know exactly?

Comment: Could you provide the value of `solSolve[[1]][[1]]` so we don't have to run the few hours long computation?

Comment: Or if it's too big, either `Cases[solSolve[[1]][[1]], _Root, ∞]` or even `FirstCase[solSolve[[1]][[1]], _Root, {}, ∞]` for that matter.

Comment: The sticky point is the final assertion. Obtaining radical solutions is not trivial even when they exist. The change of variables (introducing a level of radical nesting) has the effect of making the task trivial in this case.

Comment: @ChipHurst You can get a good idea of the behavior, but much faster, by changing parameters to numbers: `polysNum = 
 Numerator[Together[eqOrig[[All, 1]]]] /. 
  Thread[Array[b, 8, 0] -> RandomInteger[{-20, 20}, 8]]` and then set result to zero and solve.

Comment: @MarcoB The true problem can be stated in this way. Given system of polynomial equations determine (for sure) if the solution of the system can be expressed in terms of radicals. If the answer is affirmative, then find the solution in terms of radicals. The point is that if solution is expressible in radicals, then explicit formula of a general case of a problem can be provided (the interesting case). If not, then only particular cases can be analyzed (far less interesting case). The Root objects provide little insight  into problem. They are useful mainly  from computational point of view.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau   Is it possible to construct (in principle) a predicate RadicalSolutionExistsQ[polysys_], which would determine whether the radical solution of a system of equations exists? Before I encountered this example I was sure, that ToRadicals[ ] always yields the constructive answer. Seems like this is not the case. In fact the provided example  is an attempt to find an explicit formula of Sqrt of multivector of Cl30 Clifford algebra. Since ToRadicals yielded false I was sure the explicit formula is impossible. Then I noticed the substitution, which has changed our conclusion.

Comment: Such a function would involve hardcore computational Galois theory. Beyond that, I don't know what else might be needed.